# How to fill 4 SPSS variables with the values 1 to 4 using both VECTOR and LOOP?

Tags: loops, vector, spss

I want to fill 4 variables, X1 to X4 with the values 1 to 4 (case 1 getting value, case 2 getting value 2, etc). Now I manage to fill only X1, I don't know why the code doesn't continue to also fill X2, X3 and X4.

I tried this with a vector and loop, but it only fills the first variable (X1) with the correct values and then stops. So X2 to X4 stay empty.

```
DATA LIST LIST / X1 X2 X3 X4.
BEGIN DATA
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
END DATA.

VECTOR V=X1 to X4.

LOOP #i=1 to 4.
LOOP #j=1 to 4.
COMPUTE V(#i)=#j.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: why the `end case` ? if you remove it, you will end up with `4` in all variables. Is this what you are aftert ? probably not :). Best to also post the desired behavior - i.e. what you want to achieve

Comment: Please add to your post a table with the results as you would like to get from running the loop, and/or clarify a little more what it is exactly you're trying to get.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I want to create this ouput: a variable X1 containing value 1 in case 1, value 2 in case 2, value 3 in case 3 and value 4 in case 4. I want the same data in the variables X2, X3 and X4

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand exactly what you need (or what you need it for), but to get a variable to contain the digits 1,2,3,4 in consecutive lines you don't need a loop - try this:

```
compute x1=mod($casenum,4) + 4*(mod($casenum,4)=0).
```

You can of course loop through a few variables to perform the same calculation:

```
do repeat x=x1 to x4.
    compute x=mod($casenum,4) + 4*(mod($casenum,4)=0).
end repeat.
```